# grid view is not refreshing automatically after capturing a image

Tags: javascript, java, android, performance, android-studio

I tried to create an app which captures images and save to a specific folder and it will show the taken photos in grid view.  But after capturing the image, it is not reflecting immediately in the grid view, but after taking the next capture it will update. Kindly help to update the capturing image in the grid view immediately after capturing. Also kindly help, how to resize the captured image size restrict to maximum 300 kb size, that should be saved in the specific folder.

```
package com.example.surveyassist;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class CaptureActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
private DateFormat dateFormata = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String currentImagePath =null;

final int CAMERA_CAPTURE = 1;
private GridView grid;
private List<String> listOfImagesPath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_capture);

    grid = ( GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridviewimg);
    listOfImagesPath = null;
    listOfImagesPath = RetriveCapturedImagePath();
    if(listOfImagesPath!=null) {
        grid.setAdapter(new ImageListAdapter(this, listOfImagesPath));
    }
    nxtbuttonset();
}

public void captureImage(View view) {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null)
    {
        File imageFile = null;
        try {
            imageFile = getImageFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (imageFile !=null)
        {
            Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.surveyassist.fileprovider", imageFile);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_REQUEST);
        }


    }


}

private File getImageFile() throws IOException {

    final String folderpath = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");

    String timeStamp = dateFormata.format(new Date());
    String imageName = timeStamp;

    String _path = folderpath +File.separator + timeStamp+".jpg";


    File imageFile = new File (_path);
    currentImagePath=imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
    return imageFile;

}

public void nxtbuttonset() {

    Button buttonnext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNexta);

    buttonnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             // Intent intenta = new Intent(CaptureActivity.this, ZipActivity.class);
              //startActivity(intenta);
            moveTaskToBack(true);
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    });
}

//user is returning from capturing an image using the camera\

public void retrive() {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    final String folderpath = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");

    String timeStamp = dateFormata.format(new Date());
    String imageName = timeStamp;

    String _path = folderpath + File.separator + timeStamp + ".jpg";
    File f = new File(_path);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    try {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, options);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(_path);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    listOfImagesPath = null;
    listOfImagesPath = RetriveCapturedImagePath();
    if (listOfImagesPath != null) {
        grid.setAdapter(new ImageListAdapter(this, listOfImagesPath));
    }


}
private List<String> RetriveCapturedImagePath() {

    final String folderpath = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
    List<String> tFileList = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File(folderpath);
    if (f.exists()) {
        File[] files=f.listFiles();
        Arrays.sort(files);
        for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++){
            File file = files[i];
            if(file.isDirectory())
                continue;
            tFileList.add(file.getPath());
        }
    }
    return tFileList;
}
public class ImageListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    private List<String> imgPic;
    public ImageListAdapter(Context c, List<String> thePic)
    {
        context = c;
        imgPic = thePic;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        if(imgPic != null)
            return imgPic.size();
        else
            return 0;
    }
    //—returns the ID of an item—
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    //—returns an ImageView view—
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ImageView imageView;
        BitmapFactory.Options bfOptions=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bfOptions.inDither=false;                     //Disable Dithering mode
        bfOptions.inPurgeable=true;                   //Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory, the Bitmap can be cleared
        bfOptions.inInputShareable=true;              //Which kind of reference will be used to recover the Bitmap data after being clear, when it will be used in the future
        bfOptions.inTempStorage=new byte[32 * 1024];
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(context);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        FileInputStream fs = null;
        Bitmap bm;
        try {
            fs = new FileInputStream(new File(imgPic.get(position).toString()));
            if(fs!=null) {
                bm=BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fs.getFD(), null, bfOptions);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
                imageView.setId(position);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(500, 400));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            if(fs!=null) {
                try {
                    fs.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return imageView;
    }
}
}
```

and the layout code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".CaptureActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeGridLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridviewimg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="620dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"></GridView>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="57dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/RelativeGridLayout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonCam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:onClick="captureImage"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/camerabutton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonNexta"
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:background="@drawable/btn"
        android:text="Exit"
        android:textSize="19dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you should override onActivityResult()

Comment: Thanks, but can you specify where to implement the override?

Comment: in your activity